# JavaScript window object to Android view

Tags: javascript, android, webview, nativescript

i need to convert a JavaScript window object to Android native view(nativescript) i want to build a plugin from a JavaScript map for web to a nativescript map that doesn't need a webview

Comment: May I know which map you are talking about? Generally, the vendor would provide a native library which you could use for mobile apps.

Comment: Leaflet map JavaScript for html

Comment: Looks like Leaflet doesn't have a native library, you must have to use a WebView only if you want to include their map in your apps.

Comment: I already have check out my app on GitHub https://github.com/devyaz/NativeScript-Leaflet-Map but i honestly want to use Native views just like mapbox gl but ut eats so much ram and on low spec phones app crashes

Comment: How do i go about it if you can point me in the right direction, i tried asking Eddyvebrugen for help but i didn't get help